# I keep getting an error trying implementing midpoint method solving ODE

Tags: matlab, numerical-methods, ode

I am trying to implement Midpoint formulas `y[n+1/2] = y[n] + h/2 f (x[n], y[n])` and `y[n+1] = y[n] + h *f (x[n] + h/2, y[n + 1/2])`

[image]

so it solves ODE using midpoint method.

My function is

```matlab
function [ x, y ] = Midpoint_ODE ( f, xRange, yInitial, numSteps ) 
  % f = name of file with function
  % xrange Interval
  % x(1) first meaning of x
  % x(2) second meaning of x
  x=zeros(numSteps+1,1);
  x(1) = xRange(1);
  h = ( xRange(2) - xRange(1) ) / numSteps; % calculated step size
  y(1,:) = transpose(yInitial);
  for n = 1 : numSteps
    y(n+0.5,:)= (y(n) + (h * 0.5)*(transpose(feval( f, x(n), y(n)))));
    y(n+1,:) = y(n,:) + h * transpose(feval(f, x(n)+ (h/2), y(n+0.5,:))); %evaluating the function
end
```

But I get an error  :

```
**Index in position 1 is invalid. Array indices must be positive integers or logical values.
Error in Midpoint_ODE (line 11)Index in position 1 is invalid. Array indices must be positive integers or logical values.
Error in Midpoint_ODE (line 11)**
```

I checked it a couple of times, and can't get what's wrong and if I missed some logical piece.

Comment: It's because of this `y(n+0.5,:)`. Index should be integer, but you are trying to access to 1.5

Comment: Note that the error message tells you exactly the problem: "Index in position 1 is invalid. Array indices must be positive integers or logical values." It also tells you where it occurred, line 11. So you know that on line 11, you have used incorrect indices. The array indexing operations on line 11 are `y(n+0.5,:)`, y(n)`, and `x(n)`. So one of those three is causing the error. Matlab error messages are usually very helpful, take the time to read them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to keep the half-step value. Thus the easiest is to not have in in the list of values

```
  for n = 1 : numSteps
    yhalfstep = (y(n,:) + (h * 0.5)*(transpose(feval( f, x(n), y(n,:)))));
    y(n+1,:) = y(n,:) + h * transpose(feval( x(n)+ (h/2), yhalfstep)); 
  end
```

Also remember that in matlab and similar, a single-index access to a multi-dimensional array gives back the element of the flattened array (column first). That is, in `a=[ 1,2;3,4;5,6]` you get from `a(3)` the number `5` as the 3rd element in the first column, while `a(3,:)` gives the 3rd row `[5,6]`.